# Update db with latitude and longitude when google map marker point is move

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

Well, I've a google map where all lat and long comes from db and it's showing on the map.

What I can do with this map:

1) I can create new point after right click on the map,
2) I can delete existing point.

Now can you plz tell me how can i update the db with new lat and long when the existing marker point is move to another place ?

you can see my live map on www.creativeartbd.com/map

**Index.php page code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api    
/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(23.721869, 90.390518); //Google map 
Coordinates
var map;

map_initialize(); // initialize google map

//############### Google Map Initialize ##############
function map_initialize()
{
        var googleMapOptions = 
        { 
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            maxZoom: 15,
            minZoom: 5,
            zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
    scaleControl: true, // enable scale control             
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), 
googleMapOptions);          

        //Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
        $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
            $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
          var name      = $(this).attr('name');
          var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
          var type      = $(this).attr('type');
          var point     = new 
google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));
create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "icons/pin_blue.png");
            });
        }); 

        //Right Click to Drop a New Marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            //Edit form to be displayed with new marker
var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
'<form action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
'<label for="pName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pName" 
class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>'+
'<label for="pDesc"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" 
placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+
'<label for="pType"><span>Type :</span> <select name="pType" class="save-type"><option 
value="restaurant">Rastaurant</option><option value="bar">Bar</option>'+
'<option value="house">House</option></select></label>'+
'</form>'+
'</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker 
Details</button>';

//Drop a new Marker with our Edit Form
create_marker(event.latLng, 'New Marker', EditForm, true, true, true, 
"icons/pin_green.png");
        });

}

//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, 
Removable, iconPath)
{                 

    //new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello World!",
        icon: iconPath
    });

    //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
    var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
    '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
    '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
    MapDesc+ 
    '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove 
Marker">Remove Marker</button>'+
    '</div></div>');    


    //Create an infoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //set the content of infoWindow
    infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);

    //Find remove button in infoWindow
    var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
    var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];

    //add click listner to remove marker button
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
        remove_marker(marker);
    });

if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
    {
        //add click listner to save marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) 
{
            var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); 
//html to be replaced after success
var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; //name input field value
var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; //description input 
field value
var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value; //type of marker

            if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')
            {
                alert("Please enter Name and Description!");
            }else{
                save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, 
mReplace); //call save marker function
            }
        });
    }

    //add click listner to save marker button        
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window 
    });

    if(InfoOpenDefault) //whether info window should be open by default
    {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}

//############### Remove Marker Function ##############
function remove_marker(Marker)
{

    /* determine whether marker is draggable 
    new markers are draggable and saved markers are fixed */

        //Remove saved marker from DB and map using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
        var myData = {del : 'true', latlang : mLatLang}; //post variables
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){
                Marker.setMap(null); 
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });


}

//############### Save Marker Function ##############
function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
{
    //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
    var myData = {name : mName, address : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, type : 
mType }; //post variables
    console.log(replaceWin);        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "map_process.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
            replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
            Marker.setDraggable(true); //set marker to fixed
            Marker.setIcon('icons/pin_blue.png'); //replace icon
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
        }
    });
}

});
</script>


</head>
<body>             
<h1 class="heading">My Google Map</h1>
<div align="center">Right Click to Drop a New Marker</div>
<div id="google_map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Map_process.php code**

```
// database settings 
$db_username = 'username';
$db_password = 'pass';
$db_name = 'db';
$db_host = 'my host';

//mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not connect to db!'); 
exit();
}

################ Save & delete markers #################
if($_POST) //run only if there's a post data
{
//make sure request is comming from Ajax
$xhr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
if (!$xhr){ 
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Request must come from Ajax!'); 
    exit(); 
}

// get marker position and split it for database
$mLatLang   = explode(',',$_POST["latlang"]);
$mLat       = filter_var($mLatLang[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$mLng       = filter_var($mLatLang[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

//Delete Marker
if(isset($_POST["del"]) && $_POST["del"]==true)
{
$results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM markers WHERE lat=$mLat AND lng=$mLng");
    if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not delete Markers!'); 
      exit();
    } 
    exit("Done!");
}

$mName      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mAddress   = filter_var($_POST["address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mType      = filter_var($_POST["type"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO markers (name, address, lat, lng, type) 
VALUES ('$mName','$mAddress',$mLat, $mLng, '$mType')");
if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not create marker!'); 
      exit();
} 

$output = '<h1 class="marker-heading">'.$mName.'</h1><p>'.$mAddress.'</p>';
exit($output);
}


################ Continue generating Map XML #################

//Create a new DOMDocument object
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); //Create new element node
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); //make the node show up 

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");
if (!$results) {  
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not get markers!'); 
exit();
} 

//set document header to text/xml
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
 $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
 $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
 $newnode->setAttribute("name",$obj->name);
 $newnode->setAttribute("address", $obj->address);  
 $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $obj->lat);  
 $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $obj->lng);  
 $newnode->setAttribute("type", $obj->type);    
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Thanks a ton for you help :)

Answer (score 3):

You should add an even listener to the marker that is fired when the marker is dropped.

```
// adds an event listener on the marker. 
// The event is fired when the marker is dropped in this case
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    alert('Marker dropped');
});
```

Don't forget to set the marker option `draggable:true`

Here is the doc for the methods and events for the Marker class: [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker)

And here a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LGJb/2/)