# how do i update new latitude and longitude when existing google marker move to another place

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I am using google map to place markers on a map. The gps coordinates of the markers are stored in a mySQL database. I have been able to create the markers on the map so I was wondering how can i update the db with new latitude and longitude when existing marker is move to another place Here is my code so far:

live work: http://creativeartbd.com/map/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api   
/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(23.721869, 90.390518); //Google map 
Coordinates
var map;

map_initialize(); // initialize google map

//############### Google Map Initialize ##############
function map_initialize()
{
var googleMapOptions = 
{ 
    center: mapCenter, // map center
zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
maxZoom: 15,
minZoom: 5,
zoomControlOptions: {   
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
},
scaleControl: true, // enable scale control             
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), 
googleMapOptions);          

//Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
$.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
$(data).find("marker").each(function () {
var name        = $(this).attr('name');
var address     = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
var type        = $(this).attr('type');
var point   = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('latitude')),parseFloat($(this).attr('longitude')));
                  create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "icons/blue-icon.png");
            });
        }); 

        //Right Click to Drop a New Marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            //Edit form to be displayed with new marker
            var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
            '<form action="ajax-save.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
            '<label for="pName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>'+
            '<label for="pDesc"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+
            '<label for="pType"><span>Type :</span> <select name="pType" class="save-type"><option value="restaurant">Rastaurant</option><option value="bar">Bar</option>'+
            '<option value="house">House</option></select></label>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker Details</button>';

            //Drop a new Marker with our Edit Form
            create_marker(event.latLng, 'New Marker', EditForm, true, true, true, "icons/pin_green.png");
        });

}

//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{                 


    //new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello World!",
        icon: iconPath
    });

    //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
    var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
    '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
    '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
    MapDesc+ 


    '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove Marker">Remove Marker</button>'+       
    '</div></div>');    




    //Create an infoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //set the content of infoWindow
    infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);

    //Find remove button in infoWindow
    var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
    var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];

    //add click listner to remove marker button
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
        remove_marker(marker);
    });

    if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
    {
        //add click listner to save marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
            var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); //html to be replaced after success
            var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; //name input field value
            var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; //description input field value
            var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value; //type of marker

            if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')
            {
                alert("Please enter Name and Description!");
            }else{
                save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mReplace); //call save marker function
            }
        });
    }

    //add click listner to save marker button        
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window 
    });

    if(InfoOpenDefault) //whether info window should be open by default
    {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}

//############### Remove Marker Function ##############
function remove_marker(Marker)
{

    /* determine whether marker is draggable 
    new markers are draggable and saved markers are fixed */

        //Remove saved marker from DB and map using jQuery Ajax
        var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
        var myData = {del : 'true', latlang : mLatLang}; //post variables
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){
                Marker.setMap(null); 
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });


}

//############### Save Marker Function ##############
function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
{
    //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
    var myData = {name : mName, address : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, type : mType }; //post variables
    console.log(replaceWin);        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "map_process.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
            replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
            Marker.setDraggable(true); //set marker to fixed
            Marker.setIcon('icons/blue-icon.png'); //replace icon
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
        }
    });
}

function update_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
{
    //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
    var myData = {name : mName, address : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, type : mType }; //post variables
    console.log(replaceWin);        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "map_update.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
            replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
            Marker.setDraggable(true); //set marker to fixed
            Marker.setIcon('icons/blue-icon.png'); //replace icon
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
        }
    });
}   

});
</script>
```

Comment: isn't this the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688530/update-db-with-latitude-and-longitude-when-google-map-marker-point-is-move) you asked 2 days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map_process.php` should return the `insert_id` of the marker that has been inserted into the DB.

Store this ID as a `Marker`-property and pass it to `map_update.php` in `update_marker()` , then you be able to update the existing row by using the ID in a `WHERE`-clause